# Nature has been attributed with approved human values and ideals to validate and raise above debate particualr visions and ideologies

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Nature has been attributed with approved human values and ideals to validate and raise above debate particular visions and ideologies. *(Coates, "Nature: Western Attitudes Since Ancient Times, [page 5](https://books.google.ru/books?id=2uiuBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA5&ots=zjXY-ufPnF&dq=Nature%20has%20been%20attributed%20with%20approved%20human%20values%20and%20ideals%20to%20validate%20and%20raise%20above%20debate%20particular%20visions%20and%20ideologies.&hl=ru&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=Nature%20has%20been%20attributed%20with%20approved%20human%20values%20and%20ideals%20to%20validate%20and%20raise%20above%20debate%20particular%20visions%20and%20ideologies.&f=false)*)

I am confused, please explain this sentence. The language is bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nature has been attributed with approved human values and ideals to validate and raise above debate particular visions and ideologies.

Throughout human history, people have been assigning attributes to nature.

What attributes? For example, "nature is benevolent". Or, to the contrary, "in nature, every living thing constantly struggles against other living things".

When a person or a society approved of some particular value or ideal, they have tended to assign particular attributes to nature, in order to strenghen their position in their argument with other people. To quote from the same page of the book,

> The Nazis, for instance, regarded war as society's **natural state**, while a naturist recruitment film of the 1950 was titled "Naked, **as nature intended**".

Why have different persons and societies attributed nature with "human values and ideals"? In order to promove their favorite visions and ideologies.

Ideologies are often based on premises that are debatable. So in order to "lift up" your favorite ideology above debate, a Nazi could say to a liberal:

> "Well, why should we debate this at all? Just look at nature: all things are in constant struggle. So war is a natural thing. Thus, the Nazi ideology is logical in this regard, and your liberal pacifistic ideology is a failure. At least this part of the Nazi ideology is **undebatable**, is **above debate**."

---

We can reformulate the sentence thus:

> Some people, in order to validate their favorite visions and ideologies or raise these visions and ideologies *above debate*, have been attributing nature with values and ideas that are compliant with these visions and ideologies.

---

P.S. Look how a [fatalistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatalism) **vision** is **validated and raised above debate** by evoking nature and its laws. What's always implied in arguments of this kind is that mankind is only a part of a larger system and should not invent "its own" rules and laws.

> We bow down to the universal laws,
>     Which never had for man a special clause
>       Of cruelty or kindness, love or hate:
>     If toads and vultures are obscene to sight,
>     If tigers burn with beauty and with might,
>       Is it by favour or by wrath of Fate?
>
> All substance lives and struggles evermore
>     Through countless shapes continually at war,
>       By countless interactions interknit:
>     If one is born a certain day on earth,
>     All times and forces tended to that birth,
>       Not all the world could change or hinder it.
>
> (*[The City of Dreadful Night](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1238/1238-h/1238-h.htm)*)